# Solspace custom mini calendar

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar

I've been going off of the custom mini calendar found at the bottom of the page here: http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/mini/

What I'm trying to do is get a complete mini month to show but right now, with the code below, I'm only receiving the week in which 'today' resides (refer to this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVZcs.png).

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
        <div class="columns four">
          {exp:calendar:cal}
            {!-- Custom mini calendar --}
            {display_each_month}
              <table>
                <thead>

                  {!-- Display Month and Prev/Next month nav --}
                  {!-- TODO: segment properly to new cal pages --}
                  <tr>
                    <th colspan="1">
                        <a id="prev_month" class="icon left" href="{path='calendar/mini'}/{prev_month format="%Y/%m"}/">&lt;</a>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="5" id="month_title">
                      <a href="{path='calendar/mini'}/{month format="%Y/%m"}/">{date format="%F %Y"}</a>
                    </th>
                    <th colspan="1">
                      <a id="next_month" class="icon right" href="{path='calendar/mini'}/{next_month format="%Y/%m"}/">&gt;</a>
                    </th>
                  </tr>

                  {!-- Display week day letter headding ( S M T W T F S ) --}
                  <tr>
                    {display_each_day_of_week}
                      <th>
                        {day_of_week_one}
                      </th>
                    {/display_each_day_of_week}
                  </tr>

                </thead>

                <tbody>
                  {display_each_week}
                  <tr>

                    {display_each_day}
                    <td>
                      {!-- as stated above, this is only showing the week for which the date today resides in --}
                      {day}
                    </td>
                    {/display_each_day}

                  </tr>
                  {/display_each_week}
                </tbody>

              </table>
            {/display_each_month}
          {/exp:calendar:cal}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding these parameters:

```
date_range_start="year-month-01"
date_range_end="year-month-last"
```

Without them the cal tag will assume the start date is today.

Comment: This did it! When you look at something for too long your brain will eventually turn to mush :p Thank you for being active on this community; I'm sure you know that for small businesses all over the world your products reduce headaches by a factor of {event_total}. Cheers!